# Error opening a database from a Silverlight App hosted in IIS

Tags: silverlight-4.0, iis-7.5, silverlight-5.0

I'm trying to create a Silverlight App hosted in IIS (Windows 7, VS 2010) but I get this error:

[image: k]

Here's what I did:

- I created a Silverlight Application (Silverlioght 5)
- I entered on the Silverlight.Web project properties and checked "Use Local IIS Web Server" (I leaved "Use IIS Express" and "Override Application root URL" unchecked)
- I created an ADO .NET Entity Data Model for AdventureWorks SQL Server Express database
- I created a Silverlight UserControl that simply has a datagrid created by dragging the Employee Entity Table (Data Sources) to the UserControl design surface (it created a DomainDataSource)
- Followed "How to enable remote connections in SQL Server 2008" (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) :
- But when I run the app, I get the specified error.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: See if the links in the question http://forums.asp.net/t/1558691.aspx/1 helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried granting permissions to 'IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0' to log in and access your database?  It looks like you are probably using the default credentials for impersonation.  You can also specify a custom identity on the Application Pool as well.  http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: How can I grant permissions to log in and access the AW database from IIS APPPOOL\ASP .NET 4.0?

Comment: If the SQL Server is on the same machine you should be able to CREATE LOGIN [IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0] FROM WINDOWS; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx

If not, you should use the application pool identity from the afformentioned link.

Comment: SQL Server Express in on the same machine as the database. I entered the command as "CREATE LOGIN [IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0]" and I received an error in SQL Server saying that the syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Found a complete solution, for those interested please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698286/login-failed-for-user-iis-apppool-asp-net-v4-0