# db connection string and app setting been picked up by domain layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Can anyone help with this problem, I have published website to local iis7 before publishing to web host and now none off my db connections or app setting are been picked up and as such i'm getting

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
```

My site is within a solution with 2 projects 1 project is a class library with database data and call to remote sites, the 2nd project has all my ui data, controllers helpers etc.

So I have Web.Domain and Web.UI.

If I have a basic class like the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Web.Domain.EAN
 {
public class testFromDomain : ItestFromDomain
    {
   public string testdata()
       {
       return "test from domain";
       }
    }
}
```

That works OK, so that is why I believe its a problem with my config file

Does anyone know what I doing wrong or missing.

My site is MVC4

--------------------FULL ERROR------------------

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>     Web.UI.Helpers.Weather.GetWeatherCurrentForcast.data(String id) +1947
>     System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke() +78
>     System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() +109
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +144
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +84
>     Web.UI.Controllers.d__3.MoveNext() +462
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +144
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +84
>      lambda_method(Closure , Task ) +57
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +105
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass3f.b*_3e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass39.b*_33() +124
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4f.b*_49() +838059
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass37.b*_36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass2a.b*_20() +33
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass25.b*_22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +838644
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass1d.b*_18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +51
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass8.b*_3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +51
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +282

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18034

---------------------Full code for visitor reviews------------------

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Caching;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Web.Domain.VisitorReviews
    {
    public class DisplayVisitorReviews
        {
        public string ForumImageID      { get; private set; }
        public string ForumPostTitle    { get; private set; }
        public string ForumCity         { get; private set; }
        public string ForumRegion       { get; private set; }
        public string ForumCountry      { get; private set; }
        public string ForumPost         { get; private set; }
        public string ForumRatePost     { get; private set; }
        public string ForumMember       { get; private set; }
        public string ForumImageType    { get; private set; }
        public byte[] ForumImage        { get; private set; }

                  public DisplayVisitorReviews(string ForumImageID,
                                               string ForumPostTitle,
                                               string ForumCity,
                                               string ForumRegion,
                                               string ForumCountry,
                                               string ForumPost,
                                               string ForumRatePost,
                                               string ForumMember,
                                               string ForumImageType,
                                               byte[] ForumImage)
            {
            this.ForumImageID       = ForumImageID;
            this.ForumPostTitle     = ForumPostTitle;
            this.ForumCity          = ForumCity;
            this.ForumRegion        = ForumRegion;
            this.ForumCountry       = ForumCountry;
            this.ForumPost          = ForumPost;
            this.ForumRatePost      = ForumRatePost;
            this.ForumMember        = ForumMember;
            this.ForumImageType     = ForumImageType;
            this.ForumImage         = ForumImage;
            }
        }
    public class GetVisitorReviews : IGetVisitorReviews
        {
        private string dbConn;

        public GetVisitorReviews()
            {
            dbConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Website"].ConnectionString;
            }
        public IEnumerable<DisplayVisitorReviews> DisplayTopTenVisitorReviews(string id)
            {
            //string cacheTopTenDestinationReports        = "TopTenDestinationReports + "-"+ id";
            //string TopTenDestinationReportsCacheKey     = cacheTopTenDestinationReports;
            //MemoryCache CacheTopTenDestinationReports   = MemoryCache.Default;

            //if (CacheTopTenDestinationReports.Contains(TopTenDestinationReportsCacheKey))
            //    return CacheTopTenDestinationReports[TopTenDestinationReportsCacheKey] as IEnumerable<DisplayVisitorReviews>;

            string spName = "dbo.GetTopTenForumPosts";
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(dbConn))
                {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, cn))
                    {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@strLocation", SqlDbType.VarChar, 150));
                    cmd.Parameters["@strLocation"].Value = id;

                    List<DisplayVisitorReviews> lst = new List<DisplayVisitorReviews>();
                    try
                        {
                        cn.Open();
                        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default))
                            {
                            if (rdr.HasRows)
                                {
                                while (rdr.Read())
                                    {
                                    DisplayVisitorReviews GetData = new DisplayVisitorReviews(
                                                                                   Convert.ToString((Guid)rdr["ForumImageID"]),
                                                                                   (string)rdr["ForumPostTitle"],
                                                                                   (string)rdr["ForumCity"],
                                                                                   (string)rdr["ForumRegion"],
                                                                                   (string)rdr["ForumCountry"],
                                                                                   (string)rdr["ForumPost"],
                                                                                   Convert.ToString((int)rdr["ForumRatePost"]),
                                                                                   (string)rdr["ForumMember"],
                                                                                   (string)rdr["ForumImageType"],
                                                                                   (byte[])rdr["ForumImage"]);
                                    lst.Add(GetData);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        //CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
                        //policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
                        //CacheTopTenDestinationReports.Add(TopTenDestinationReportsCacheKey, lst.AsEnumerable(), policy);

                        return lst;

                        }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                        throw new ApplicationException(ex.InnerException.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Web.Domain.VisitorReviews
    {
    public interface IGetVisitorReviews
        {
        IEnumerable<DisplayVisitorReviews> DisplayTopTenVisitorReviews(string id);
        }
    }


kernel.Bind<IGetVisitorReviews>().To<GetVisitorReviews>().InSingletonScope();

 private readonly IGetVisitorReviews _IGVR;

    public MembersController(IGetVisitorReviews IGVR)
        {
        _IGVR = IGVR;
        }

public PartialViewResult pvVisitorReviews()
            {

                var destinations = _IGVR.DisplayTopTenVisitorReviews("NA").Take(5);
                return PartialView("pvHomePageVisitorReviews",destinations);
            }

 <add name="Website" connectionString="Data Source=Windows7\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=WebsiteDB;Persist Security Info=true; Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I have added full code for Reviews, the reason been has the shortest amount of code. Also If I comment out the weather partial view, the same error then goes to the reviews, if I comment out the reviews or anything else that if referenced from the web.config the site loads.

------------------------Full Error after surrounding connection settings in class-------------

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


 Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 





Line 87:                 <div class="dvAsyncDestination">
Line 88:                    
Line 89:                   @{Html.RenderAction("pvVisitorReviews", "Members", true);}
Line 90:                    
Line 91:                 </div> 

Source File: f:\LocalTestSite\Views\Home\Index.cshtml    Line: 89 

Stack Trace: 





[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Web.UI.Controllers.MembersController.pvVisitorReviews() +184
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +78
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +260
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +33
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +123
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +838059
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +33
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +838644
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Wrap>b__3() +15
   System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Func`1 func) +41
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride) +1783

[HttpException (0x80004005): Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.]
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride) +2819
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage) +275
   System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +94
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter) +700
   DevTrends.MvcDonutCaching.HtmlHelperExtensions.RenderAction(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, Boolean excludeFromParentCache) +233
   DevTrends.MvcDonutCaching.HtmlHelperExtensions.RenderAction(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, Boolean excludeFromParentCache) +17
   ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute() in f:\LocalTestSite\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:89
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +126
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +143
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +181
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +378
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +33
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +854172
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +265
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +838644
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +51
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288



--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18034
```

Comment: We need more information to help. What code is throwing the exception? What does your web.config look like? Also, the object reference not set exception, is not what the exception I would expect if you had a bad connection string.

Comment: Hi Jeff, its all data that has a connection string in the web.config file or an config section that gets its data from web.domain

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem and it only took 1 day :-( for anyone else who ever has this problem please view this link [Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698286/login-failed-for-user-iis-apppool-asp-net-v4-0)

The link posted above put me on the right track, but Microsoft recommend using ApplicationPoolIdentity so this is what I did to solve the problem.

1. Open SQL and then open Security
2. Click logins and the right click and select new login
3. Give it a name IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0
4. Then default database select the database you want
5. Click server roles and select public
6. Click user mapping and select owner and public, (I had to select both in order for this to work)
7. Click ok then come out of Security
8. Now click on your database and select security
9. Click on users and select IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0
10. Right click the select properties
11. Clck owned schema and then select datareader and datawriter
12. Click membership and select owner

Click ok and now go back to IIS manager and the click browse website and your site should now work in IIS.

3 points I'm not happy about.

1. select owner in user mapping, does this really need selecting, if not how can I secure the connection better
2. Again selecting owner in membsership, why did i need to select this in order for this to work.
3. Finally all the books I have read, none say anything about having to add IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 to the database security. If this is the only way to get this to work, come on authors, please add this information to your books, it would have saved me a days work.

I'm not a professional programmer and I'm just learning by trail and error and reading books. So if any one else can add to the above please do so.

Thanks

George

Answer (score 0):

When you publish your website, it only publishes the Web.config of your Website project, not the one of your class library project. You'll have to manually add the connection string to the Web.config of your website.

Comment: Hi Henk, I put a class into the web.ui with a call to db and still get the same error.

Comment: Here is my db config Data Source=Windows7\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=WebsiteDB;Persist Security Info=true; Integrated Security=SSPI, as said earlier, works ok when using iss express but once publish does not work

Comment: Where is the connection string stored, in the App.config of the class library project or the Web.config of the Website project?

Comment: Hi Henk in web.config in website project

Comment: Then please show us some more code, when do you get the error?

Comment: I have added the error, I'm unable to work out to to debug the site once it has been published to iis7 as all i have in the site is dll files, no classes etc

Comment: Can't you just show us your source code? It has something to do with the weather forecast class. We need to see where  and how you make a connection to the database.

Comment: Have added full code for reviews, as explained in new code, I can comment out any partial view that gets its data from either the database or remote site and the error goes to next one, comment them all out and page loads

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24884/discussion-between-careerchange-and-henk-mollema)