# How to configure ASP.NET site on IIS 7.0

Tags: asp.net, iis, configure

I found a lot of articles on internet about "Deploying ASP.NET website on IIS 7.0" and now i know that how to do it.
But unfortunately when i set website on the IIS, i get another error! At the first i got "IIS APPPOOL\TradeSite" error. but, when i changed IDENTITY of related Application Pools to LOCALSYSTEM it solved. After that i got new error message with this specification:

**Server Error in '/' Application.
Cannot open database "TradeSite" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.**

please help me how to fix this problem.

i add sites with this method:

1. copy published project to wwwroot folder of IIS
2. Add new web site in IIS and Set their port to a unique port number ex:8090
3. Change .Net framework version from 2.0 to integrated 4.0
4. Change process model identity to LOCALSYSTEM from advance setting menu

that's it. it was all the work that i did.

also, I read [somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698286/login-failed-for-user-iis-apppool-asp-net-v4-0) that you should open an connection to SQL, i don't know was it a correct solution or not, but i did it but again nothing changed.
Also i tested on both Server and Local IIS but the result was same.

it will be my pleasure that anyone help me on this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your TradeSite db hosted in SQL Server?  If so, open up the database in SQL Server Management Studio, select Security, and ensure that Network Service has access to at least read from the database.

Comment: thank you for your attention.

Yes, TradeSite DB hosted on SQL express 2008 R2.
according to your answer I did it but nothing changed.

this is my LOGIN list from SECURITY folder:

 1. ##MS_PolicyEventProcessingLogin##
 2. ##MS_PolicyTsqlExecutionLogin##
 3. BUILTIN\Users
 4. NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
 5. NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER
 6. sa
 7. Administrator

I set my database for  NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER but problem exist yet.

could you explain how to add read or write access to Network Service please? Where is Network Service option? i couldn't find it.

Thanks.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647402.aspx Look for the portion that mentions SQL Server