# Connection String for ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, sql-server-2008

I am trying to connect to a database from an ASP.NET web application.  However, I am getting the following exception:

**Cannot open database "Books" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0'.**

This is the connection string that I am using:

```
<add name="DB_Connection" connectionString="data Source=.\ANTONIO;Initial Catalog=Books;Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

This is a screenshot of the server that I am trying to connect to:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?  Is the connection string wrong?  Or is it something else?

**Update**

This project was deployed on IIS server.  I removed it from IIS server and started it as a normal project.  It works so the problem is not the connection string.

It seems that the IIS server account is not able to access my database.  How can I solve this please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698286/login-failed-for-user-iis-apppool-asp-net-v4-0

Comment: @Damith Thank you very much Damith :)  I am taking a look at the question page right now

Comment: Thank you so muuuuccchhhh :))))))))))  The solution suggested on the question page worked :))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server Management Studio you need to go to Security -> Logins -> Create New then create a new Windows login for your IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 user.  Then in User Mappings give the new login the needed access to Books.  You can give it read/write/alter privileges as needed.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that your connection string is coming through in your post.

The first thing I would test is to ensure that you can connect to the SQL database with the user account directly.

The second thing I would check is to ensure your APPPOOL has the correct permission on the site folder.  Typically a site will have an APPPOOL based on the site name rather than the .Net version...

If you can get your connection strings to display, I could better troubleshoot.

Also... you may want to check http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/