# After Hosting Asp.Net App on IIS 7.5 it shows login page but do not login in Application my WebConfig file attached?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, sql-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

i have tried a lot to host application on iis i hosted on iis 5.1 on win xp but problem  same it do not login just shows login page after that i tried to host it on IIS 7.5 win 7 it is doing same just showing login page i have changed its web config credentials according to it as i am using sql server 2008 R2 i have given connection string according to it i am attaching my web config here under showing environment sqlserver 2008 R2 , iis 7.5 , win 7  please review it and let me know if there is any error,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Error,ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
                <listeners>
                    <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
                        <filter type=""/>
                    </add>
                    <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
                        <filter type=""/>
                    </add>
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
        <sharedListeners>
            <add initializeData="F:\Work\08-14-09\Source\InspectionEvaluation\web_tracelog.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
                <filter type=""/>
            </add>
        </sharedListeners>
    </system.diagnostics>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Inspection" connectionString="Data Source=HASSANALI-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Inspection;Integrated Security=SSPI; Persist Security Info=false; Trusted_Connection=Yes;Connect Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
        <add name="InspectionDesign" connectionString="Data Source=HASSANALI-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=InspectionDesign;Integrated Security=SSPI;           Persist Security Info=false; Trusted_Connection=Yes;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
        <add name="inspectionConStr" connectionString="Server=NY-IT-Tabish\LOCALDEV;Database=Inspectionp;User ID=sa;Password=capslock;Trusted_Connection=False;"/>
        <add name="InspectionEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Inspection.csdl|res://*/Inspection.ssdl|res://*/Inspection.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=OFFICE-7398439B\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Inspection;User ID=musewerx;Password=123456;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>

    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>

        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="Microsoft.Vbe.Interop, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"/>
                <add assembly="office, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"/></assemblies></compilation>

        <authentication mode="Windows"/>

        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/></system.web>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <services/>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICIService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8731/InspectionServices/CI/" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICIService" contract="CIService.ICIService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICIService"/>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Hopes for your suggestions thanks

Comment: have you tried to debug your application?

Comment: my application is running fine its not logging after hosting from iis

Comment: @All Application pool identity is problem that was causing issue

Comment: this link help me out "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698286/login-failed-for-user-iis-apppool-asp-net-v4-0"

Comment: After lots of googling, this leads me to the correct answer, thanks! (.net 6)