# wcf - 400 bad request when host in IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, iis, wcf-binding

I found so many questions with similar problem, but couldn't find solution for this. in my case i wrote wcf rest service and then created client application and connected. (in local host) and then it connected and working properly.
After that i host my wcf service in IIS and change my client application to IIS link. then it gives me following error.

```
The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
```

My **web config** as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="LibraryMgtSysEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataLibraryMgtSys.csdl|res://*/DataLibraryMgtSys.ssdl|res://*/DataLibraryMgtSys.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=tt\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=LibraryMgtSys;Persist Security Info=True;user id=sa;password=testing;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=tt\SQLEXPRESS;          Initial Catalog=LibraryMgtSys;          Integrated Security=SSPI;          user id=sa;password=testing;" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <membership defaultProvider="SqlMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="LibraryMgtSys" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="LibraryMgtSys" name="SqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <profile enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="LibraryMgtSys" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="LibraryManagementService.MobileService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding"
        contract="LibraryManagementService.IMobileService" />
      </service>

    </services>

    <bindings>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>  
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

What i miss in here?

Comment: your endpoint doesnot have an address specified. You need to provide a base address for your service and provide a endpoint address as well. At the client side you need to specify the baseaddress/endpointaddress.

Comment: @Saranya - IIS provides the base address.  If no address is provided in the endpoint, the base address will be used (in this case, the location of the .svc file).

Comment: @DevT did you check the service by open it from IIS ?

Comment: @ShujaatSiddiqui - yes when i open it from iis then it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this problem occurs to me because of database connection problem. When I'm host my web service in IIS its need to give access rights to database for IIS user. i configure database settings as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20765115/1395178)

Answer (score 1):

400 bad request refers that the request send does not respect the HTTP protocol and is not well formed. 
As you said it was working fine before you host it on IIS.

1. if its rest GET api just paste the url on browser and check is it working fine ?
2. If yes mean you have a problem in client application
3. If No then i would suggest you to check the service contract / or you did not host the service properly on IIS.