# Keep getting "Login failed for user IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool" no matter what I do

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, sql-server-2012-express

I'm trying to give an ASP NET App access to a database (These are test only not production).

It's the first time I try it in this network, and I haven't done it with VS2012, SQL Server 2012 Express, Windows 7 before

What I have done:

- **I upgraded my Sql Server 2012 Express** since what VS2012 first installs is a version that doesn't allow access from IIS
- I found that I had to configure SQL Server 2012 Express to accept **remote connections**, then I followed a good blog I found  [here](http://www.linglom.com/it-support/enable-remote-connection-on-sql-server-2012-express/)
- In SSME 2012, I added a new login for all databases **NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE** (I browsed it and found "Servicio de red" which stands for NETWORKSERVICE, so it is actually **NT AUTHORITY\Servicio de red**)
- I set dbo as the default schema for this login
- Under login properties, in **User Mappings**, I checked my Database (which I named MiniNorthwind) and then checked db_datareader and db_datawriter in Database Role Membership for MiniNorthwind
- In Internet Information Services Manager I checked that the DefaultAppPool Identity was **ApplicationPoolIdentity** (It was the default setting)

But I still get an error saying that **Login failed for user IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool**, if I change the DefaultAppPool identity to NetworkService, then the error changes to **Login failed for user NT AUTHORITY\Servicio de red**

I don't know what else to do. Please, need help here.

Rafael

Comment: My connection string is set to Integrated Security, and I'd like to keep it that way. I also want to use the deffault app pool, I think it is possible.

Comment: I'm doing it all in a laptop connected to a network, it's installed with Win7 Ultimate x64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In IIS Manager set DefaultAppPool identity as NetworkService. Although it works, you should try to make it work with AppPoolIdentity, since it the Windows 7 attempt to make it safer

Answer (score 10):

application pools -> your application pool used in application -> click it and then click 'Advance Settings' in panel. Find 'Identity' property and change it to localsystem.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the ApplicationPoolIdentity from IIS7 -> Application Pools -> Advanced Settings.

Under *ApplicationPoolIdentity* you will find *local system*. This will make your application run under `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`, which is an existing login for the database by default.

For more info Look at this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8853386/1676736

Comment: I am sorry, I am allowed only once to up vote your answer!. Finally I understood this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Change your connection string.

For example:

```
//< add name="CS"  connectionString="server=.;database=JackDB;user id=sa;password=ya;">
```

This solves the error.

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers didn't work for me.....

What I needed to do was go to application pools, right click on my website, go to advanced settings and by identity instead of the default built in account application pool identity, I needed to set a custom account and put in the username and password my hosting company gave me.

Answer (score 1):

> When we tried to hit api login method for url
>   ("http://api.xyz.com/v1/login") which we have registered in
>   '**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts**' file and hosted on IIS. Then we got an error **Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'. Cannot open database**" But after running below query on database the problem resolved.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool')
BEGIN
    CREATE LOGIN [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool] 
      FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], 
      DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
END
GO
CREATE USER [WebDatabaseUser] 
  FOR LOGIN [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool]
GO
 EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'WebDatabaseUser'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to change my `connectionString` from :

```
<add name="DatabaseName" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=HrAndPayroll;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

to :

```
<add name="DatabaseName" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Initial Catalog=HrAndPayroll;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

After I deployed my project, my `connectionString` got modified hence removing `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf`, so I had to give the link of my database explicitly in the `connectionString`.