# MVC: workflow is not working in deployed server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, workflow, web-deployment

In our MVC web application, we have integrated windows workflow. Its working locally without any issue. After deployment of the application in windows server 2008, workflow functionality is not working. I am not getting any error. But the application in browser is keep on running with no result.
Note: .Net4.5 framework is installed in server.
When I googled, I found few solutions and I tried the below

Right click the web site that hosts your service in the IIS Connections pane, click Manage Websites -> Advanced Settings and add ,net.pipe to the end of the “Enabled Protocols” setting (no spaces!)

Still facing the issue. Please guide to fix this issue

When I see the event viewer, I observed an information saying that 
"Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0'. Reason: Token-based server access validation failed with an infrastructure error. Check for previous errors."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added user, "IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0" to DB Logins by openning SQL Management Studio, Navigate to database then open the Security then Logings and add new login. It solved the issue.

Comment: Did you add user "IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0" like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698286/login-failed-for-user-iis-apppool-asp-net-v4-0
or to your database?

Comment: @StepUp:I have added the user as shown in the link, which you posted