# Cannot obtain metadata from wcf, 404 error

Tags: xml, vb.net, wcf, http, metadata

I am doing the last tutorial in a book pro vb 2008 in chapter 25 working with wcf web-centric project. I am currently getting an error saying that it cannot obtain my metadata and I get a 404 error while running my service. Please help. I am using `http://localhost` and my files sit here
`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\VbAutoLotWCFService`

Service.svc

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="VB" Debug="true" 
Service="VbAutoLotWCFService" 
CodeBehind="~/App_Code/VbAutoLotWCFService.vb" %>`
```

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings/>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes for .NET 4.5 see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <!--
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.

            Visual Basic options:
            Set strict="true" to disallow all data type conversions 
            where data loss can occur. 
            Set explicit="true" to force declaration of all variables.
        -->
    <compilation debug="false" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <namespaces>
        <clear/>
        <add namespace="System"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Specialized"/>
        <add namespace="System.Configuration"/>
        <add namespace="System.Runtime.Serialization"/>
        <add namespace="System.ServiceModel"/>
        <add namespace="System.Text"/>
        <add namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions"/>
        <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Caching"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.SessionState"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Security"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Profile"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
  </system.web>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <!--
              Uncomment this section to enable the authentication service. Include 
              requireSSL="true" if appropriate. 

          <authenticationService enabled="true" requireSSL = "true|false"/>
          -->
        <!--
              Uncomment these lines to enable the profile service, and to choose the 
              profile properties that can be retrieved and modified in ASP.NET AJAX 
              applications.

           <profileService enabled="true"
                           readAccessProperties="propertyname1,propertyname2"
                           writeAccessProperties="propertyname1,propertyname2" />
          -->
        <!--
              Uncomment this section to enable the role service.

          <roleService enabled="true"/>
          -->
      </webServices>
      <!--
        <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="true" enableCaching="true" />
        -->
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
  <!--
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="VbAutoLotWCFService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IAutoLotService"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: 404 means the resource can't be found.   Did you set up an application pointing to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\VbAutoLotWCFService` in IS?

Comment: When creating my project I selected file -> new web site -> WCF Service under visual basic. For the Web Location I chose HTTP. This puts the files in the c:\inetpup\wwwroot directory. Perhaps IIS isn't picking this up. I do not know.

Comment: I started iis and now i at least have access but am getting the error. 500.19
Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost

Error Summary
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Comment: Step 1: Enable IIS
Step 2: Update IIS using this command.
c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -iru

This solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: I have access to all the methods now in my dal accessing the database but now I am getting this error.

Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.

Comment: I set includeExceptionDetailsInFaults = true and found out my error. I followed the answer to this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698286/login-failed-for-user-iis-apppool-asp-net-v4-0