# SqlException: Invalid object name dbo.<tablename> when using LocalSystem as Identity

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, asp.net-web-api, localhost

I deployed a asp.net web api on my local IIS (7.0) and I can't get through in accessing the database.

When the identity (under process model) is set to `LocalSystem`, API will return this exception:

> Invalid object name 'dbo.tablename'

If I set the identity to `ApplicationPoolIdentity`, the API will return this exception:

> Cannot open database "dbname" requested by the login. The login failed.
>    Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0'.

Solutions tried:

1. [Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698286/login-failed-for-user-iis-apppool-asp-net-v4-0)
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18-zatWd68s
3. Added permissions to both folder and .mdf file to 'ASP.NET v4.0'
4. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/12/08/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-2-instance-ownership/

Other relevant information:

connection string (in `web.config`)

```
<add name="DbContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=[dbname];Trusted_Connection=Yes;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I also tried running the application using Visual Studio using IIS Express, it worked fine.

Comment: You've already seen https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/12/08/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-2-instance-ownership/  It says you basically have 3 options, run IIS as your ID (bad idea), run localdb as a shared instance, or use SQL Express - the last is probably the best advice.

Comment: You're right, I passed that info after working for long hours, wasn't thinking clearly at that time.. I used sqlexpress instead of localdb..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already seen https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/12/08/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-2-instance-ownership/

It says you basically have 3 options,

- run IIS as your ID (bad idea),
- run localdb as a shared instance, or
- use SQL Express

The latter is probably the best advice.

Comment: I tried 2nd approach , first I do this 
sqllocaldb share v11.0 IIS_DB 
I change my data source to (LocalDb)\v11.0.\IIS_DB it gives network instance error.