# Login failed for User when deployed in IIS and executing stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, stored-procedures

I am executing a stored procedure in an asp.net application hosted in local IIS . I am using SQL LocalDB v11.0 for my database .
Here is my connection string

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=IntMonkey;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
```

When I run my code  it gives error

```
Cannot open database "IntMonkey" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.
```

My application pool is set to DefaultAppPool . I tried to set identity to Network Service and Local System but same error for those users.
I have created Logins for [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool] , [NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE] , [IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0] and assign User Mapping to this database with roles as db_owner , db_writer and db_reader but still not working.
It works fine when running without IIS.

Need help what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: have you directly tried to connect from sql management studio using these new logins?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981518/sqlexception-invalid-object-name-dbo-tablename-when-using-localsystem-as-iden

Comment: Yes they are login successfully

Comment: I tried Approach 2: Use LocalDB Shared Instance
sqllocaldb share v11.0 IIS_DB run this and change my conn string to 
Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0.\IIS_DB;;Initial Catalog=IntMonkey;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;

but now it gives Network Instance error .