# Thinktecture IdentityManager doesn't work on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, identity, thinktecture, identitymanager

I have published Thinktecture IdentityManager Asp.net sample on Visual Studio 2015 and added the web site to IIS 8, all in the same machine. The site appears ok on the browser but when I try to list/create any user or role I get the error: "An error has occurred" . The same example works perfectly running on Visual Studio but not on IIS. What can be happening?. Any solution for not to return to MS Web Admin Tool?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried checking error logs?

Comment: Hi mason, how can I do that?.. I have been watching some Fiddler data but seems so complex...

Comment: Open up the Event Viewer on the server. Expand Windows Logs and then view Application. You'll probably see error messages in there related to your issue.

Comment: I have open the Browser Console and I have get: "An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details. "...In the Inner Exception I can see: f/<() Scripts.Bundle.js:117
ye/this.$get</m.prototype.$eval() Scripts.Bundle.js:131
ye/this.$get</m.prototype.$digest() Scripts.Bundle.js:128
ye/this.$get</m.prototype.$apply() Scripts.Bundle.js:132
k() Scripts.Bundle.js:90
v() Scripts.Bundle.js:95
af/</z.onreadystatechange().................That has no sense for me.....

Comment: Hi mason....I see this in the XML error on Event Viewer (usermanager4 is the name of the app):                                                                                         <Data>IIS APPPOOL\usermanager4</Data> 
  <Data>Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'AspIdentity'.</Data> 
  <Data>[CLIENT: <local machine>]</Data>                                                                                                             .....................I don't know the reason for it to not be able for opening the database......

Comment: Thanks mason, here is the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698286/login-failed-for-user-iis-apppool-asp-net-v4-0