# Cannot open database "MyDatabaseName" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\MyAppName

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

I have created a web application. I am using SQL 2012 express as a database. Its working fine when I am running on debug mode. When I deployed that application on local IIS it's throwing an error

> Cannot open database "databaseName" requested by the login. The login failed.
>    Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\MyApplicationName'.

My connection string is `<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=HAPPY\SQLEXPRESS;uid=sa;password=123;Initial Catalog=dwm;integrated security=sspi;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

I am able to login with this login detail on my SQL 2012 express. I am attaching a screenshot [image].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698286/login-failed-for-user-iis-apppool-asp-net-v4-0)

Comment: follow this link for solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698286/login-failed-for-user-iis-apppool-asp-net-v4-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `SSPI` Integrated Security, thus it is trying to use Windows authentication. Try setting to `False`:

```
 connectionString="Data Source=HAPPY\SQLEXPRESS;uid=sa;password=123;Initial Catalog=dwm;integrated security=False;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your web application uses a `SSPI` Integrated Security.

You have those options :

Either add the `IIS APPPOOL\MyApplicationName` as a login and give the required rights to the database `dwm`.
But since this login is probably not known from the SQL Server you might have to change the Login used by your WebAppPool with a service account from the AD that is shared with your SQL Server.

Or change the connection string with a SQL Login (which has the required rights) - it is not recommended to use the `sa` login also. Also using this method reduces the security.

```
connectionString="Data Source=HAPPY\SQLEXPRESS;uid=mySqlLoginForMyApplicatioNName;password=itsPassword;Initial Catalog=dwm;integrated security=False;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me EF was not creating the database and navigating to the application gave me the following -

> "Cannot open database “MyDatabaseName” requested by the login. The
>   login failed. Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\MyAppName"

Restarting the website within IIS solved my issue.