# Connection string using local SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, web-config, connection-string

How to write the connection string to local SQL Server database using `web.config`?

Here is my connection string in `web.config`. But when I open local/demo, it said:

> login failed for user ''.

Actually I'm using Windows authentication, so I thought it doesn't need user and password.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="HRISContext" 
         connectionString="data source=.;initial catalog=BPSDEMO;Pooling=false;persist security info=True;user id=;password=;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: You need to add Integrated Security in connectionstring. `<add name="HRISContext" connectionString="data source=.;initial catalog=BPSDEMO;Pooling=false;persist security info=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  />` For more information check 
https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/

Comment: I already added the integrated security. Then the error:  'Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'. @MohsinMehmood

Comment: It indicates that your application is trying to connect to SQL database using Application pool identity. One way to fix is to add IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool user to database. Checkout this SO answer for step by step instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698286/login-failed-for-user-iis-apppool-asp-net-v4-0

Comment: How about this?
 `<add name="HRISContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\BPSDEMO.mdf;Initial Catalog=BPSDEMO;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" /> `

The error message: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - @MohsinMehmood

Comment: This will only work if you have your database mdf file inside `App_Data` folder. Basically, this option allows you to deploy your database file along your project.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Windows authentication, then **yes**, you **must not** include any `user id` and `pwd` in your connection string - just remove those completely. But you **must** include the `Integrated Security=SSPI` setting instead.

Try this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="HRISContext" 
         connectionString="data source=.;initial catalog=BPSDEMO;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Pooling=false;persist security info=True;App=EntityFramework" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  />
</connectionStrings>
```